# What is the "Correct" MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am following MVVM pattern in my project and I got stuck when I came across a scenario, I don't have any clue how to handle in a proper MVVM way.

My scenario is I have lot of polyline in my view. Am displaying and positioning then using Itemscontrol. Every thing is fine. My problem is the user should be able to click on a polyline and each point in the line should be shown as Ellipse, and user should be able to capture the Ellipse and move so the the polyline will be updated.

Question: I can handle the Mouse click using the `ICommand` Then from were I will draw the Ellipse, Drawing from Viewmodel is not MVVM way. and how to handle the mouse actions on dynamically created Ellipse.

Option 1:

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Line}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <Grid>
                            <Polyline  Stroke="Black" Points="{Binding PolyLinePoints}"  >

                            </Polyline>

                        </Grid>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
```

And Handle the Command in the View model and draw thw ellipse from there.

```
 if (LinePoints.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (Point p in LinePoints)
                {

                    Ellipse eli = new Ellipse();
                    eli.Width = 8;
                    eli.Height = 8;
                    eli.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    eli.Fill = Brushes.White;
                    eli.Name = "Circle";
                    eli.MouseLeftButtonDown += eli_MouseLeftButtonDown;
                    eli.MouseMove += eli_MouseMove;
                    eli.MouseLeftButtonUp += eli_MouseLeftButtonUp;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(eli, p.X);
                    Canvas.SetTop(eli, p.Y);
                    Canvas.SetZIndex(eli, 2000);
                    canvas.Children.Add(eli);
                }
            }
```

option 2:

Draw and handle completely from Code behind

Is there a better option to solve such scenarios ?

Comment: Put the code you're using to draw ellipses.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa i have added that code. from were i handle that code? code behind or from were i handle my Command.

Comment: You should not be drawing anything in the view model at all.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul I know that but what i dont know is How to tackle this

Comment: Handling as you show in the VM is ok.  You have address-ability to everything you need. But, also remember that you can put it in the View Code behind because it's only dealing with the view and arrangement of the view.  However, some may argue that it goes too far by adding content, not just rendering it.  How do you handle mouse actions on dynamically created things?  Simple you add the event handler at the time you create them, something you are not doing now.

Comment: Use `ItemsControl`, `Canvas` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`, and in `ItemTemplate` XAML, set `Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top`.

Comment: @user1522548 its not only just drawing each mouse action such as moving a ellipse will update the ellipse location to the database. thats why am confused.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa am not sure i understood you, you want me to add one more Itemscontrol for Ellipse and position them using Canvas in ItemspanelTemplate?

Comment: My naive approach would be to encapsulate the drawing and visual logic into a new control, and expose data binding points that the VM is responsible for populating. The VM can quite rightly hold the line points data that the view uses to drive the drawing, but the actual behaviour of the view should be held within it (usually as a control).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Could you provide a small example or link.

Comment: Don't confuse database actions with view actions.  They are two different concerns.  First worry about getting the view right, then put in the code to handle the database side.

Comment: @N.J Unfortunately I don't have any. But the idea is the same as with the baked in controls. You let the grid worry about drawing the rows and columns, you just bind the tabular data. Make a control that draws your stuff and ask for data to control what to draw.

Comment: Looks like everyone misunderstood your question. Change the ItemsControl to a `ListBox` and use the `IsSelected` to determine whether or not to show your selection indicator and draggable `Thumb`s.

Comment: @HighCore true everyone misunderstood, I should try out the method you have mentioned.

Comment: @user1522548 My question was Is It the right way that referencing a "view" item "canvas" in the ViewModel to apply the drawing.

Comment: The general answer in MVVM is that the viewmodel only contains the collection of items on the canvas.  The canvas is "Bound" to the collection. Binding can happen in the view or the viewmodel and all it does is establish the relationship of the View to the collection of items to display.